# glTexImage2DMultisample gives error with SNORM internal formats

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

glTexImage2DMultisample gives GL_INVALID_ENUM error when called with snorm internal formats. when i checked http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2DMultisample.xml , and it does not specifies any operation with error GL_INVALID_ENUM. 
Is snorm formats are supported for that API or not?

Comment: And if you use it with a regular format does it work ok? If it does then glTexImage2DMultisample probably doesn't support these.may be you pass a wrong enum somewhere else in the method?If you show your code then may be the help will come faster.

Comment: @MichaelIV: It works perfectly with other enums. About support, where can i get an exact info about it, i didn't find that anywhere. But i don't think there should be any reason of not supporting snorm texture formats with multisampling.

Comment: Then I am curious too :)